# How to write if else statement with a value with multiple value set?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So for my 'f' value, it has from 1-15. How do I write my if-else statement if I want if f value == 1,6,7,8,9,10,12 it does something if-else f value == 2,3,4,5,13,14,15 do something else?

```
 if(a == "BLK A ", d == "BLK D ", e == "5", f == "1 "){
        // do something
    } 
    else if (f =="6"){
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to check a range of values for `f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with the wanted values.

It is necessary to take the same type of the value, like string or numbers. If different types, you need to normalize the value to all numbers or strings.

```js
 
if (['1', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '12'].includes(f)) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `parseInt()` function:

```
var valueOfF = parseInt(f)

if(valueOfF >=1 && valueOfF <=10){

    //doSomething
}
else if(valueOfF >=11 && valueOfF <= 15){

    //doSomething
}
```